# Как создать Large Text программно?

Tags: java, android

Как с помощью java создать объект Large Text?

Необходимо присвоить ему alighParent и id, чтобы потом с ним делать, что угодно, уничтожать, перемещать, устанавливать текст.

Comment: что такое `объект Large Text`? Таких объектов нет в стандартном Android Framework

Answer (score 1):

Ну id присваивается командой setId();
А создание самого элемента в коде будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
// создание LinearLayout
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // создаем LayoutParams  
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
        // устанавливаем linLayout как корневой элемент экрана 
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
```

Только вместо LinearLayout TextView

Comment: А можно точно пример, а то студия не знает что такое LayoutParams и я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал что-то типо TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
        myTextView.setText("Enter Text Below");

        int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        RelativeLayout.addView(myTextView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));

Comment: Если ответ правильный, пометьте его галочкой.

Comment: Это почти правельный, как все это перевести в код? Или дайте статью чтоли, android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"